# split string into groups of given size

Tags: python, string, performance, datetime, split

My situation is I have a list of time-stamped items, but the actual time-of-day is all squished together. Like this:

```
time = "165420" # 16:54:20 (or, 4:54 PM and 20 seconds.)
```

I wanted a script to go over the lines and be able to convert the time-stamp into a date-time. I have the year, month, day already that was no problem. But for the time situation I was desperate to find an elegant and simple solution. I decided to brute force it at first to continue with my code, and ended up with:

```
import datetime

dt_timestamp = extract_dt("2012-11-09-165420") # example

def extract_dt(timestamp):
    ds = timestamp.split('-') #split into groups (0,1,2 are the date, 3 is the time.
    d = [int(i) for i in ds[:3]] + [int(ds[3][0:2]), int(ds[3][2:4]), int(ds[3][4:6])]
    return datetime.datetime(*d)
```

While trying to solve my situation I've seen many variations on this question, with many answers.

I have found [this solution](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/157385-splitting-string-into-groups-three-characters):

```
def nsplit(s, n):
    return [s[k:k+n] for k in xrange(0, len(s), n)]
```

Which works nicely for me:

```
>>> s = "165420"
>>> n = 2
>>> [s[k:k+n] for k in xrange(0, len(s), n)]
['16', '54', '20']
```

But I am pretty sure there MUST be a better, more elegant way of splitting a string into groups of equal size, as was mentioned in the [link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/157385-splitting-string-into-groups-three-characters) I provided (but fixed because the link poster had a typo):

> TheFunction("Hello World",3)
>
> Returns:
>
> ['Hel','lo ','Wor','ld']

I would prefer, if possible, that it not be a function, I want a way to do it in-line. And it should be as efficient as possible. I can always extract the list-comprehension from the function I found, but I have a feeling its not very efficient, and it just doesn't look right.

The answer is probably something very simple I just didn't know about. Thanks again.

Comment: question has been answered - however, i would still like to know if anyone by any chance comes across this, if they find a better solution to splitting strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a more elegant solution to chunking strings than those you mention in your question, but [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) solves your practical problem:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("2012-11-09-165420", "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 9, 16, 54, 20)
```

Comment: thats wonderful, i cant believe i didnt think of a local solution for datetime, since it is the datetime that output that style, it must be able to get it as input as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`textwrap.wrap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) for this:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = "165420"
>>> n = 2
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, n)
['16', '54', '20']
```