# Python divide user in put by 4

Tags: python, list, operators, divide

How can I divide the user input by 4?

```
example = input("Enter input")
```

so `abcdefghjklmnopqrstu` is 20 characters and I want to divide them by 4 so Ill have 5 characters list then I will append them all into a newlist?

I am new to python and using Python IDLE 3.3

I would like to get the total of user's input character then divided them by 4 so when I want to append them to a list it would look something like this

```
list = [abcde],[ghijk],[lmnop],[qrstu]
```

Here is my current code

```
user = input('ENTER TEXT: ')
user.upper()
print('Decrypting message: ', user)

for i in range(0, len(user), 4):
    temp.append(user[i:i+4])

for i in range(0, len(user), 1):
        print(temp[i])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [split string into groups of given size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331705/split-string-into-groups-of-given-size)

Comment: Really what you're asking is how to split a string into equal sized chunks.  It's not really relevant that the string came from an input call.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`textwrap.wrap()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap) for this:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstu"
>>> textwrap.wrap(s, len(s)/4)
['abcde', 'fghjk', 'lmnop', 'qrstu']
```

Comment: Needs to be "textwrap.wrap(s, len(s)//4)" for Python 3, which asker is using. "len(s)/4" gives floating point, which throws a TypeError when it tries to slice the string in the wrap() implementation.

Comment: @CoupleWavyLines good point. My OS still default to 2.7, nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use any library, can achieve it using loop:

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"
l = len(a); i = 0; r = []
while i < l and len(a) >= 4:
    r.append(a[:l/4])
    a = a[l/4:]
    i += l/4
print (r)

['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst']
```

Comment: Python is not C and this has issue with edge cases: try with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx`

Comment: @sudo_O: Yes you are correct Python is not C; Python have full-fledged library support which is it's plus point; but I thought to give this solution for newbiees as the person who is asking question(Mr.T) has mentioned that he is new to python so I just wanted to let him know all ways to solve above problem; with or without library.

Comment: When I said Python is not C I was referring to style only... it's not very pythonic.

Comment: okay; but it is python program; any ways I will keep it in mind.